# Determining kind of data encoded in tifs

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, metadata

I have tifs and with help from this community I have been able to navigate them with gdal, rasterio, geopandas etc.
I also understand that they encode [raster data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413646/understanding-rasterio-index-coordinates).
But I am not sure what additional metadata is encoded in them.

Is there some way for me to browse through the metadata and make this information more human readable in python?

I would like to leverage this metadata in an ML problem, but I don't just want to throw it into a neural network to figure it out.

Comment: Other than asking the creator for more specific information about these data you could use gdalinfo to read the infomation stored in the TIFF.  https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html

Comment: @GBG thanks, this seems like the most straightforward way to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- One way is contacting the developer/owner/project manager/scientist who puts the `.tif` files online.

2- Another way is to read the `.tif` description (some kind of internal metadata that is available via `.tif` format.

3- Is to locate the bounds and look at its aerial/satellite images and speculate what it might be.

4- If your raster is accompanied by an `*.hdr` or `readme.txt`, open them in a text viewer and you'll possibly find all the information

Comment: thank you very much for this list, 1 I did it's a 3rd party so we didn't get far.
2) how do I read the .tif description? 
3) I am doing this right now and feel a little lost.
4) unfortunately no such file.

Comment: Open the `.tif` in any GIS software, then right-click on the `.tif` layer -> properties. Under `meta-data` or something similar you will typically find a lot!

Comment: Oh, I see, so there likely isn't much here then: https://i.imgur.com/BSVzW9G.png ? I'm using QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use 'pyexiftool' for this particular case, which is a python wrapper for the useful program 'exiftool': http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/

It has built in functionality to handle multiple images, which will be handy for you when mining for ML inputs.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this looks very useful, I haven't gotten it to work fully yet though